# Runtime error 91 assistance

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting the "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set" error. When I click on debug button, the "Debug.Print sht.Name" is highlighted in yellow. All I am wanting to do is loop through the sheets and Step In(F8) the program and watch the sheet names display in the Immediate box. Thank You.

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopSheets()

Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet

WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count


For I = 4 To WS_Count
    Debug.Print sht.Name
Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't define `sht`. I guess you need `set sht=worksheets(I)`.

Comment: `Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name`

Comment: Not Dim the sht and Set sht=worksheets(I) as suggested displays a "Compile error: Variable not defined"

Comment: I don't understand your comment. As Tim suggests sht is in any case redundant.

Comment: I'm sorry. I saw my error. I did not delete the "Set sht= worksheet(I). Thank you Tim it worked. Part one of three solved.

Comment: The problem was not caused by not deleting that line, you needed to add it for the approach you were using.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really catch why you loop from the 4th sheet and onwards, but to print out **all** the sheet names, you can do it with the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopSheets()
Dim sht As Worksheet

    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Debug.Print sht.Name
    Next sht

End Sub
```

Hope this helps you achive your goal. :)